# Incomplete implementation on left side

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have incomplete implementation warning on my implementation page (the same functions is on the right.m file):

left.m file

```
#import "left.h"
#import "shareL.h"

@interface left ()

@end

@implementation left    // Incomplete implementation

- (IBAction)shareL {

    shareL *screen = [[shareL alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle :nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];

}


- (IBAction)backButton {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Why is incomplete implementation? On the right side I have same functions and everything it's OK.

Comment: You should share `left.h` and see what methods you've declared there. Also, if you expand the compile error, it will tell you the name of the method that it was looking to be implemented, but never found.

Comment: As @Rob says above, without the header, it's hard to know what you are missing.  Also - and this has nothing to do with your missing method implementation - your Objective-C class name `left` is unconventional.    See Apple class [naming standards](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-1002242-BBCIJGDB)  By convention, class names are nouns, and begin with a unique upper-case prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By opening up the incomplete implementation warning you can find out exactly what method(s) you may be missing implementations of.  Below is a screenshot that illustrates what the issue may be.  In my case I'd commented out a method called fadeAction

[image]